# Microsoft access db error editing record

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access application which use SQLServer 2008 R2 as database.

When I try to update a single record I get this error:

> "3179 the microsoft Jet databse engine stopped the process because you
>   and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same
>   time"

This error append only on this particular record (and a few others) and append every time I try to update it.
The application (and db) runs as single user and **I don't have** a thread running at the same time update the same record

[image]

I get this error on every machine I try so it should not related to SQLServer.

**EDIT**
I have try to update the record directy in SQL Server and no problem, the updare it's ok.

I found that the problem is when I update one of four Text field (es.Note) from Microsoft access.

When i run the script below i have the error only for a particular record (Cod_stabile=6600015) with the others records no 
problem.  Update for others fields it's ok, the error there is only with Text fields.

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

. . .

StrSql = "SELECT St_Stabili.* FROM St_Stabili WHERE (St_Stabili.Cod_Stabile='6600015') ;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSql)
rs.Edit
rs!Note = '-'
rs.update  <- error


. . .

StrSql = "SELECT St_Stabili.* FROM St_Stabili WHERE (St_Stabili.Cod_Stabile='6600016') ;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSql)
rs.Edit
rs!Note = '-'
rs.update  <- OK!
```

Thank you very much

Comment: When you say you do not have a thread running, are you sure that you are not opening a recordset in code or another form or subform? Do you get an error when you try to update this record in the linked table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing the method used to update the TEXT fields:

```
Dim UpdCommand As ADODB.command
    Set UpdCommand = New ADODB.command
    With UpdCommand
        .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "UPDATE St_Stabili SET NoteStabile= ?" _
                                      & ",NoteGenerali = ?" _
                                      & ",NoteConteggio = ?" _
                                      & ",NoteAmministratori = ?" _
                & " WHERE St_Stabili.Cod_Stabile = ?;"

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NotaSt", adVarChar, adParamInput, 300, Me!NoteStabile_x)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NotaGen", adVarChar, adParamInput, 300, Me!NoteGenerali_x)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NotaCon", adVarChar, adParamInput, 300, Me!NoteConteggio_x)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NotaAmm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 300, Me!NoteAmministratori_x)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("Cod_Stabile", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, Me!Cod_Stabile_x)
    End With

UpdCommand.Execute
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your table in SQL Server has any triggers that update the record based on your update. This appears to MS Access as another user has updated the record. Be careful if your SQL Server table has a TIMESTAMP especially in a trigger.